# What happens if the ball is bounced into the basket?

Tags: rules, basketball

What happens when I bounce-pass the ball into the basket, like in a circus shot?
Does this count as a successful basket?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, a bounce that goes into the basket would count as a successful goal.  Anytime (except on a throw-in) a live ball goes through the basket, it is a goal, and it doesn't matter who, if anyone, threw the ball.

From the [NCAA Men's Basketball 2013-14 and 2014-15 Rules](http://www.ncaapublications.com/p-4312-2013-14-and-2014-15-mens-basketball-rules.aspx), Rule 5 (Scoring and Timing Regulations), Section 1, Article 2:

> **Art. 2.** A goal is made when:
>
> a.  A live ball that is not a throw-in enters the basket from above and remains 
>   in or passes through the basket; or
>
> b.  A free throw enters the basket from above and remains in or  passes 
>   through the basket.

After a player bounces the ball, the ball is still live, meaning that any player could theoretically grab the ball and continue playing.  So if the ball goes in the basket, the goal would count.

Kicking the ball in, [even if it is easier for you](http://youtu.be/gzC11oNYx64?t=1m15s), is not allowed (NCAA Rule 9, Section 7; [NBA Rule](http://www.nba.com/media/dleague/1314-nba-rule-book.pdf) 10, Section 4).

Comment: Curious, how does defensive goal tending play in this?

Comment: @waxeagle Good question.  Goaltending is defined in Rule 9, Section 17, and can only happen during a "field goal try."  Rule 5, Section 1 defines a try, and includes language about the ball leaving the hand.  Therefore, I don't believe that they should call a goaltending penalty on a ball that was bounced or kicked in.

Comment: If you bounced the ball *inside* the 3 point line, while standing *outside* of the 3-pt line, would it be a 3 or a 2 pointer? :)

Comment: @NicholasV. At this point, I think we are speculating, but I would say that it would be a 2-pointer.  The language in Rule 5, Section 1 suggests to me that a field-goal try or a three-point try requires that the ball leave the hand and go to the basket.  The basket would count, but would probably not be officially credited to the player in the stats.

Comment: @BenMiller, alright, yeah I'm not expecting there to be anything clearly stating this situation's outcome. Thanks

Comment: This reminds me of [this classic Super Bowl ad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1shK-j_u6LI).

Comment: Sorry, but I still seem unconvinced on a few points.

One point is goaltending, as Waxeagle mentioned.
And the other is about the defintion of 2pters & 3ptrs in this case.

What happens if I attempt a shot from outside the circle, the ball heads towards the rim, narrowly misses the rim, but bounces once and heads back into the net?
Is it a 3 or a 2 ? Or something else?

Comment: @Yaitzme Not convinced? :) You won't find any explicit rules in any rulebook on these situations, because these situations never actually happen in real games.  But if they did, I believe the existing rules I cited should apply as I have discussed.  The bottom line is, if a live ball goes into a basket, it's a goal.

Comment: @Yaitzme To answer your question, if you attempt a shot from outside the 3-point line, you miss the rim, the ball bounces off the floor, goes back up and then goes down through the hoop, I would give your team 2 points, and you would not be credited with the basket.  But you would probably go viral on YouTube the next day.

Comment: There is no speculation on what a bounced basket would be worth - it is worth whatever it would be worth when it leaves shooters hands.   So you bounced it in from halfcourt via bounce on free throw line that is a 3 pointer - for sure.    Same is true if I am defending a shooter at the three point line.   I can be two feet inside the line and tip/block the shot, if it goes in it is still a 3 even though it last touched a player inside the 3 point line.   The rule is simply - where it left shooter's hand.